# Cell.Formula gives #name error until user selects formula

Tags: aspose-cells

In my program I create an excel file with a formula containing a reference to a table (listobject). When opening the resulting excel file the formula shows the `#NAME?` error until the user selects the formula and exits it again.

First I do:

```
worksheet.Cells["A2"].Formula = "=INDEX(personData, MATCH(B2, personData[displayName]), 0)";
workbook.CalculateFormula();
```

When I open the resulting workbook in excel the formula for A2 is slightly changed in capitalization:

```
=INDEX(PERSONDATA,MATCH(B2,personData[displayName]),0)
```

When focusing the formula and exiting again the formula becomes

```
=INDEX(personData,MATCH(B2,personData[displayName]),0)
```

What's the source of the capitalization?
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I've been able to narrow the problem down to the fact that the formula breaks when the referenced table is on another tab than the formula. When I move it to the same tab everything works as expected.
Updating the aspose.cells library to the most current version of aspose.cells (8.6.0.0) didn't help.
Adding a tab reference to the referenced (lookup!personData) name is invalid.

Posted short post and example code on Aspose forum as requested:
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/658097/658097/showthread.aspx#658097

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me a bug of Aspose.Cells. Please try the latest version: Aspose.Cells for .NET 8.5.2 (download from Aspose website) and it should fix this issue. Please also post this issue in the Aspose.Cells forum with your sample excel file so that we could run your code and find out the root cause of the problem.

Mostly, such an error means the Aspose.Cells is unable to calculate the formula. Could you please also save your workbook in PDF format and see does it show the correct value or error.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: thanks for the reply. Our corporate licence doesn't cover v8 I think, so getting that updated might take some time. There is no original workbook as it is created from code. Or do you mean the resulting one?

Comment: I've been able to narrow the problem down to the fact that the listobject is on another tab. Will update OP

Comment: It seems to me some sort of bug but we are not sure about it. Could you please provide us your simple sample runnable code/project in the forum that could replicate this issue. In case, the error is fixable, we will suggest you a code change and in case, it is a bug, we will log it in our database for a fix. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Babar Raza (aspose support developer) has found and logged your issue. Once, we will have update or fix for you, we will update you asap.